# Facebook in-app browser not executing javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook

**TL;DR version:**

Part of JS code in Facebook browser does not execute with each page reload - only after several reloads.

**The question:** How to make Facebook in-app browser execute all JS code each time the page loads? This should actually be normal behaviour - and, in fact, other browsers (tried Chrome and Safari) execute the code with each reload of the page.

**Details:**

On my website I have an issue related to user login/logout. The debugging process led me to the point where I put a test code on the beginning of `<head>` in order to check whether my cookie exists or not. The issue I am experiencing only happens on Facebook in-app browser.

So, I have this sample code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="da">
        <head>
            <script>
                alert(document.cookie.match(/glt_.+?;/) || 'no glt_* cookie!');
            </script>
            <!-- other <script> tags here -->
        </head>

        <body>
        ...
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

I'm sharing the url with this code on my Facebook wall, then I go to Facebook app on iPhone 6s and tap on the link; it opens in the in-app browser.

Now, this code should display an alert with either the cookie or the message saying there's no cookie. But... there is no alert at all. Like this `alert` part of code wasn't there.

However, after refreshing several times, the alert starts to appear. And once it appears for the first time, then it keeps appearing with every reload of the page, until I tap the "back" button. Then, when I'm again on my wall, and tap the link again, the whole situation repeats - the alert is not there until I refresh several times.

And for me the "alert not showing" basically means "some pieces of javascript not executing" - please let me know if I'm mistaken here, maybe alerts are treated in a specific way in this browser? Other pieces of JS (user interface etc.) work properly.

**Investigation so far:**

The issue doesn't occur on any of the popular browsers; the alert shows up each time.

Another thing: I kill the Facebook app (double-press the home button to get the list of open apps, then kill Facebook). Then I reopen Facebook, tap again on the link and... the alert doesn't appear. I refresh it several times and it eventually appears.

I also cleared the browser cache in the app settings, but this didn't affect anytning.

Comment: Same happend to us, lazy loaded images don't appear and some pieces of js look like are not being executed, but there's no way to prove that. It would be awesome to be able to test and get js traces of facebook in-app browsers

Comment: I think this is because the Facebook and Instagram in-app webview is not Javascript enabled. But, Twitter in-app webview is JS enabled. I tested my website in these three popular social media apps. For more info about FB WebView, see https://blog.tomayac.com/2019/12/09/inspecting-facebooks-webview/

Comment: We are facing similar issues, javascript redirection is not working in facebook's InApp browser.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/68101925/644949